# Getting CORS Error for Invalid POST, PATCH - REST Endpoints

Tags: javascript, rest, express, cors

I'm working on Express.js and sending data in JSON. I'm getting the CORS Error (below) when passing POST, PATCH requests on Invalid Endpoints. For valid POST, PATCH Endpoints, there is no CORS error.
Also, for invalid/valid GET endpoint requests, there's no CORS error though.

Error Message:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/invalid-endpoint' from origin 'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Fetch Command I'm sending for Invalid POST Endpoint:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/invalid-endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    someValue: "999",
   })
  }).then(response => {
  return response.json()}).then(data => {
  console.log(data)}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)});
```

Headers I've included in my application:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Complete Code:

```js
//require modules.

//Headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});

//Endpoint Routes
app.use("/state", stateRoutes);
app.use("/district", districtRoutes);
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use("/", stateDistrictRoutes);  //also Home

 /* All the invalid endpoints should fall into this. But CORS Error preventing that for POST and PATCH. GET is working fine here. */
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Invalid Endpoint.")
  error.status = 404;
  throw error;
});

//All the errors should fall into this at last.
app.use((error, req, res, next) => { 
  const status = error.status || 500;
  const message = error.message;
  res.status(status).json({
    status: status,
    message: message,
    info: error.data || null,
  });
});

//connection to database....etc.
```

P.s.:- adminRoutes.js page (/admin). Below POST/PATCH requests work perfectly.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const adminControllers = require("../controllers/adminController");
const adminAuthControllers = require("../controllers/adminAuthController");


router.post("/add/state", adminControllers.postState);
router.post("/add/district", adminControllers.postDistrict);

router.patch("/update/state/:state", adminControllers.patchState);
router.patch("/update/:state/:district", adminControllers.patchDistrict);

router.post("/login", adminAuthControllers.postLogin);
router.post("/signup", adminAuthControllers.postSignup);


module.exports = router;
```

adminControllers Page

```js
const State = require("../models/state");
const District = require("../models/district");

exports.postState = (req, res, next) => {
  const body = req.body;
  State.findOne({ name: req.body.name })
    .then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        const error = new Error("State already Exists!");
        error.status = 409;
        throw error;
      }
      const state = new State({
        ...body,
        creator: {
          lastUpdatedBy: req.userEmail,
          createdBy: req.userEmail,
        },
      });
      return state.save();
    })
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "State created Successfully!",
        data: response,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!err.status) {
        err.status = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
};

exports.postDistrict = (req, res, next) => {
  const body = req.body;
  District.findOne({
    name: req.body.name,
    state: req.body.state,
  })
    .then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        const error = new Error("District already Exists!");
        error.status = 409;
        throw error;
      }
      const district = new District({
        ...body,
        creator: {
          lastUpdatedBy: req.userEmail,
          createdBy: req.userEmail,
        },
      });
      return district.save();
    })
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "District created Successfully!",
        data: response,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!err.status) {
        err.status = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
};

exports.patchState = (req, res, next) => {
  
  const state = req.params.state;
  const body = req.body;

  State.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: state },
    { ...body },
    {
      new: true,
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "State updated Successfully!",
        data: response,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!err.status) {
        err.status = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
};

exports.patchDistrict = (req, res, next) => {
  const state = req.params.state;
  const district = req.params.district;
  const body = req.body;

  District.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: district, state: state },
    { ...body },
    {
      new: true,
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "District updated Successfully!",
        data: response,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!err.status) {
        err.status = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
};
```

Thanks!
Stay Safe.

Comment: Could you possibly show the complete code for one of your routes modules involving a valid POST or PATCH endpoint that doesn't cause such an error?

Comment: thanks @IAmDranged. I've added one of the adminRoutes POST endpoint.  It works fine if I request with the correct Endpoint, i.e. http://localhost:3000/admin/add/state/

Comment: Could you please just show the complete code for your adminRoutes module instead? Just want to see all the routes that are actually set up there.

Comment: I've added the complete code of adminRoutes and adminControllers. let me know if you need more info. thank you :)

Comment: @IAmDranged the problem seems to be with OPTIONS, which is giving 404 for invalid POST/PATCH endpoints.

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense what you're seeing for invalid endpoints. But why don't valid endpoints error out as well? I do not see any route handlers for the OPTIONS method for these either.

Answer (score 1):

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
> does not have HTTP ok status.

This error seems to indicate a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) failed because its http status was not in the 200 range. Note such preflight requests come into the picture only for CORS requests that are considered complex - such as POST or PATCH requests.

Your server is not set up to specifically handle those types of preflight requests that I can see - so these actually end up being caught by your 404 route handler and hence the error message you're seeing. What is not clear to me is why your valid POST and PATCH endpoints do not error out in a similar fashion.

In order to avoid such errors, you should set up your server to handle preflight requests for all endpoints - including invalid ones. Something along the lines of the following should do the trick:

```
app.options("*", function(req, res) {
   res.status(204).send()
)
```

Note this should come before your catch-all 404 middleware - and after the CORS middleware.

Edit: based on the below test program, it actually would appear that express automatically adds an OPTIONS route handler at the end of the middleware stack for paths to which a route handler has otherwise been explicitly attached.

```
var express = require("express");
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express()

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.get("/exist", function (req, res) {
    res.send("ok")
})

app.options("/intercept", function (req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(204)  
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server listening"))

// console output
Server listening
OPTIONS /exist 200 2.972 ms - 8         
OPTIONS /nonexistant 404 1.865 ms - 154
OPTIONS /intercept 204 0.597 ms - 11
```

As a sidenote, express also seems to add an implicit 404 handler, although this may not be what you want - the content type in particular is html.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. I've read somewhere that Express.js handles OPTIONS by default, i.e., we don't need to define app.options(...); though I'm not sure.

The trick looks like the only way to handle this issue. I found something similar to what you have shared.
`if (req.method === "OPTIONS") { res.sendStatus(200); } else {  next(); }`
We can add this line to the section where I've added **access-control-headers**.

_It still leaves us wondering why this partiality between valid and invalid POST/PATCH requests and no issue with GET endpoints._

Comment: I have just ran through a quick test, and it actually seems you're correct that express does some implicit OPTIONS route handling.